# MudDataGrid FilterDefinitions and SortDefinitions in function (ServerData) not working

Tags: c#, datagrid, blazor-server-side, iqueryable, mudblazor

I have this method to sort and filter dynamically using IQueryiable:

```
GridState<GreenPaperItem> state = null;
private async Task<GridData<GreenPaperItem>> LoadData(GridState<GreenPaperItem> state)
{
    this.state = state;

    var query = context.GreenPaperItems.AsQueryable();
    
    if (state.FilterDefinitions != null && state.FilterDefinitions.Count() > 0)
    {
        foreach (var filter in state.FilterDefinitions)
            query = query.Where(filter.GenerateFilterFunction());
    }

    if (state.SortDefinitions != null && state.SortDefinitions.Count() > 0)
    {
        foreach (var sort in state.SortDefinitions)
            query = query.OrderBy(sort.SortFunc);
    }
    else
    {
        query = query.OrderBy(w => w.Date);
    }

    int count = query.Count();

    var items = query.Skip(state.PageSize * state.Page).Take(state.PageSize)
        .ToList<GreenPaperItem>();

    GridData<GreenPaperItem> data = new()
    {
        Items = items,
        TotalItems = count
    };
    return data;
}
```

But the where and sort linq methods only get string and Expressions to return IQueryiable. And the functions inside methods are underlined red. How to make this work?
The error says it can not convert `IEnumaerable<GreenPaperItem>` to `IQueryiable<GreenPaperItem>`.

Also It cannot be translated at runtime using this code:

```
if (state.FilterDefinitions != null && state.FilterDefinitions.Count() > 0)
{
    foreach (var filter in state.FilterDefinitions)
        query = query.Where(it => filter.GenerateFilterFunction(null)(it));
}

if (state.SortDefinitions != null && state.SortDefinitions.Count() > 0)
{
    foreach (var sort in state.SortDefinitions)
        query = query.OrderBy(it => sort.SortFunc(it));
}
else
{
    query = query.OrderBy(w => w.Date);
}
```

Comment: `foreach (var sort in state.SortDefinitions) query = query.OrderBy(sort.SortFunc);` -  I hope you understand that this will actually apply only the last sort definition? =)

Comment: it says error CS0266

Comment: Even if it was not it still will not work as expected.  As for the compiler error - in my answer for your other question it is somewhat explained.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77723991/system-linq-dynamic-core-date-is-empty-date-is-not-empty) it is now working. But Advanced filtering still does not work:

```
<MudDataGrid T="GreenPaperItem" ServerData="LoadData" Filterable="true" FilterMode="@DataGridFilterMode.ColumnFilterRow" @ref="grid">
    <Columns>
        <PropertyColumn TProperty="int" T="GreenPaperItem" Property="@(it => it.Id)"
                       Filterable="true">
            
        </PropertyColumn>
        <PropertyColumn TProperty="DateTime" T="GreenPaperItem" Property="@(it => it.Date)"
                        Filterable="true">
            <FilterTemplate>
                <MudIconButton OnClick="@OpenFilter" Icon="@_icon" Size="@Size.Small" />
                <MudOverlay Visible="@_filterOpen" OnClick="@(() => _filterOpen = false)" />
                <MudPopover Open="@_filterOpen" AnchorOrigin="Origin.BottomCenter" TransformOrigin="Origin.TopCenter" Style="width:600px">
                    <MudStack Row="true" Spacing="2" AlignItems="AlignItems.Center
      " Justify="Justify.FlexStart">
                        <MudText>Between:</MudText>
                        <MudDatePicker @bind-Date="start" t Label="Start">

                        </MudDatePicker>
                        <MudDatePicker @bind-Date="end" Label="End">

                        </MudDatePicker>
                        <MudStack Row="true">
                            <MudButton OnClick="@(() => ClearFilterAsync(context))">Clear</MudButton>
                            <MudButton Color="@Color.Primary" OnClick="@(() => ApplyFilterAsync(context))">Filter</MudButton>
                        </MudStack>
                    </MudStack>
                </MudPopover>
            </FilterTemplate>
        </PropertyColumn>
        <PropertyColumn TProperty="string" T="GreenPaperItem" Property="@(it => it.Title)">
            
        </PropertyColumn>
        <TemplateColumn CellClass="d-flex justify-end">
            <CellTemplate>
                <MudIconButton Size="@Size.Small" Icon="@Icons.Material.Outlined.Edit" OnClick="@context.Actions.StartEditingItemAsync" />
            </CellTemplate>
        </TemplateColumn>
    </Columns>
    <PagerContent>
        <MudDataGridPager T="GreenPaperItem"></MudDataGridPager>
    </PagerContent>

</MudDataGrid>
```

Code:

```
 @code {
        MudDataGrid<GreenPaperItem> grid;    
        FilterDefinition<GreenPaperItem> _filterDefinition;
        DateTime? start = DateTime.Today;
        DateTime? end = DateTime.Today;
        DateTime? filterStart = null;
        DateTime? filterEnd = null;
        string _icon = Icons.Material.Outlined.FilterAlt;
    
        bool _filterOpen = false;
    
    
        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            await base.OnInitializedAsync();
            filterStart = start;
            filterEnd = end;
            _filterDefinition = new FilterDefinition<GreenPaperItem>
            {
                FilterFunction = x => x.Date.Date >= filterStart.Value.Date &&        x.Date.Date <= filterEnd.Value.Date
            };     
        }
        void OpenFilter()
        {
            _filterOpen = true;
        }
    
        private async Task ClearFilterAsync(FilterContext<GreenPaperItem> context)
        {
            filterStart = default(DateTime);
            filterEnd = default(DateTime);        
            _icon = Icons.Material.Outlined.FilterAlt;
            await context.Actions.ClearFilterAsync(_filterDefinition);
            _filterOpen = false;
        }
    
        private async Task ApplyFilterAsync(FilterContext<GreenPaperItem> context)
        {
            filterStart = start;
            filterEnd = end;       
            _icon = Icons.Material.Filled.FilterAlt;
            await context.Actions.ApplyFilterAsync(_filterDefinition);        
            _filterOpen = false;
        }
    
        GridState<GreenPaperItem> state = null;
        private async Task<GridData<GreenPaperItem>> LoadData(GridState<GreenPaperItem> state)
        {
            this.state = state;
    
            var query = context.GreenPaperItems.AsQueryable();
    
    
            if (state.FilterDefinitions != null && state.FilterDefinitions.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (var filter in state.FilterDefinitions)
                {
                    var expression = FilterExpressionGenerator.GenerateExpression<GreenPaperItem>
                        (filter, new FilterOptions() { FilterCaseSensitivity = DataGridFilterCaseSensitivity.Default });
                    query = query.Where(expression);
                }
            }
    
            if (state.SortDefinitions != null && state.SortDefinitions.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (var sort in state.SortDefinitions)
                    query = query.OrderBy($"{sort.SortBy} {(sort.Descending ? "descending" : "ascending")}");
            }
            else
            {
                query = query.OrderBy(w => w.Date);
            }
    
            bool? result = await dialogService.ShowMessageBox(
                "Warning", query.ToQueryString(), yesText: "OK", cancelText: "Cancel");
    
            int count = query.Count();
    
            var items = query.Skip(state.PageSize * state.Page).Take(state.PageSize)
                .ToList<GreenPaperItem>();
    
            GridData<GreenPaperItem> data = new()
            {
                Items = items,
                TotalItems = count
            };
            return data;
        }
```

How to make this work?