# is it possible to convert lambda function to string for use in system.linq.dynamic.core expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, dynamic, entity-framework-core

I mean to convert something like:

```
query = query.Where(it => it.Color.Contains("blue")); // to @"Color contains "blue""

or

query = query.Where(it => it.Color.StartsWith("blue")); // to its equivalent

or 

query = query.Where(it => it.Number == 2);  // to "Number == 2"
```

Lambda function (Predicate) or a collection of functions (Predicates) to its System.Linq.Dynamic.Core string Equivalent?

EDIT:

Or convert to string as is so that I use DynamicExpressionParser to convert to an expression?

Comment: Why exactly do you want that?

Comment: To solve the problem of this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77700788/muddatagrid-filterdefinitions-and-sortdefinitions-in-function-serverdata-not-w

Comment: TBH it is not clear how this will help that) I would argue that it is quite solvable without such conversion.

Comment: No I tried a lot, It can not be solved unless I have string of the lamda, or its expression but not the lamda delegate (Func<T, bool>)

Comment: Without actual [mre] it is hard to tell.

Comment: `query.Where(it => it.Color.Contains("blue"))` should work as is. Why do you want to convert it to string?

Comment: I have it => it.Color.Contains("blue") as a function but not as an expression, in the other question filter.GenerateFilterFunction() generates a Func<T, bool> and not a expression, so I need either a string representation of this to use in the query or a expression for this query to compile.

Comment: Change `GenerateFilterFunction` to create an expression (or better create a `GenerateFilterExpression`). What is the problem?

Comment: This is a a method of the state.FilterDefinitions that MudBlazor send to ServerData function for MudBlazor.MudDataGrid, I have no control over it.

Comment: Can you please provide a small repro of what are you trying to do and post it on github for example?

Comment: @mz1378, probably sometime better to check sources: [MudBlazor - GenerateFilterExpression](https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/blob/cc92141cfca099c3e45249c22b6d4a931870c98a/src/MudBlazor/Components/DataGrid/Definition/FilterDefinition.cs#L73-L83)