# System.Linq.Dynamic.Core Date is empty & Date is not empty

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, entity-framework-core, system.linq.dynamic

How to do this `Date is empty & Date is not empty` in System.Linq.Dynamic.Core,
I am currently doing this that is not working:

```
if (filter.Operator.StartsWith("is empty") ||
     filter.Operator.StartsWith("is not empty"))
 {
     filterOp = filter.Operator.StartsWith("is not") ? "!=" : "==";
     qs = $"{filter.Column.PropertyName} {filterOp} ''";
 }
 query = query.Where(qs);
```

Comment: A DateTime cannot be null.  The default date is 1/1/01.  Either test for 1/1/01 or test if the date is after a day like 1/1/2000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering bunch of your questions to help your job done this year.

1. [is it possible to convert lambda function to string for use in system.linq.dynamic.core expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77708504/is-it-possible-to-convert-lambda-function-to-string-for-use-in-system-linq-dynam)
2. [How to convert Func<T, bool> to Expression<Func<T, bool>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77702016/how-to-convert-funct-bool-to-expressionfunct-bool)

`MudBlazor` already can build filter expression and no additional crutches like `Dynamic.LINQ` are needed. I have checked this code and it should work with EF Core.

There is function:

```cs
public static class FilterExpressionGenerator
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> GenerateExpression<T>(IFilterDefinition<T> filter, FilterOptions? filterOptions)
    ...
```

So, basically you can use this function in the following way:

```cs
query = query.Where(FilterExpressionGenerator.GenerateExpression<GreenPaperItem>(filter));
```

And if you have list of these defintitions, you can create helper function which apply this list to any `IQueryable`

```cs
public static class MudBlazorFilterHelper
{
    public static IQueryable<T> ApplyFilter<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, IEnumerable<IFilterDefinition<T>> filterDefinitions)
    {
        foreach(var filter in filterDefinitions)
        {
            query = query.Where(FilterExpressionGenerator.GenerateExpression<T>(filter));
        }
        return query;
    }
}
```

Answering the following comment:

> but for checking that it is not enumerable at the end, I get the error "The given 'IQueryable' does not support generation of query strings." when I want to convert the query ToQueryString()

Extension method `ToQueryString()` you can call ONLY when `IQueryable` started from `DbSet`, it is not applicable to `IQueryable` created from `IEnumerable` by calling `AsQueryable()`. These `IQueryable` has different `Provider` and `ToQueryString()` expects that this provider is specific EF Core provider.

Comment: what about advanced filtering it seems that is not work in advanced filtering.

Comment: What is "Advanced Filtering"? I don't know MudBlazor, but can read their sources.

Comment: https://www.mudblazor.com/components/datagrid#advanced-filtering

Comment: I do not see why it should not work. Show your code in .NET fiddle.

Comment: I posted codes here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77700788/muddatagrid-filterdefinitions-and-sortdefinitions-in-function-serverdata-not-w/77731414#77731414

Comment: You should not use `FilterFunction`, build FilterDefinitions with Operator, value and column or duplicate somehow using Expression. From my side it is better when `MudBlazor` will introduce `FilterExpression` property.

Comment: Also you can look at [DelegateDecompiler](https://github.com/hazzik/DelegateDecompiler)